# Show that for every set $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ lebesgue measurable $\int_{A} f_n dx\rightarrow \int_{A} f dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $f_n$ and $f$ functions of $L_1\mathbb R^n$ such that
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n = f$ almost always in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f_n|\ dx\rightarrow \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|\ dx$. Show that for every set $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ lebesgue measurable
$$\int_{A} f_n\ dx\rightarrow \int_{A} f\ dx.$$
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe try the *dominated convergence* theorem for $f_n\cdot{\bf 1}_A$ where ${\bf 1}_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$.

Comment: Hi, Berci. Could you be more specific? I confess that I didn't understand very well. To use the dominated convergence theorem, shouldn't the norm of $f_n(x)$ be bounded by an integrable function?

Comment: I used 'maybe' in the comment to express my uncertainty about my suggestion.

Comment: [Scheffé's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma) guarantees that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$, and so, you may apply DCT here. Or, you may open up the proof of this lemma and adapt the key steps (which, of course, utilizes the Fatou's lemma) to your problem.

Comment: To add to @SangchulLee comment, my hint is the first step in the proof of this lemma, after which the desired result follows quickly

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & |f_{n}|\\
 & = & |\left(f_{n}-f\right)+f|\\
 & \leq & \left|f_{n}-f\right|+\left|f\right|.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\leq0\leq2|f|$. On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|f_{n}-f\right|\\
 & \leq & |f_{n}|+|f|,
\end{eqnarray*}
re-arranging terms yields $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\geq-2|f|$. It follows
that
$$\left||f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\right|\leq2|f|.$$

Observe that $|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\rightarrow0$ pointwisely a.e.. By
Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that
$$
\int\left(|f_{n}|-|f|-|f_{n}-f|\right)dm\rightarrow0.
$$
It is given that $\int\left(|f_{n}|-|f|\right)dm\rightarrow0$, so
$\int|f_{n}-f|dm\rightarrow0$. In particular, for any measurable
set $A$, $\left|\int_{A}f_{n}dm-\int_{A}fdm\right|\leq\int_{A}|f_{n}-f|dm\leq\int|f_{n}-f|dm\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Danny. I have doubts about your solution: because $|f_n| - |f| - |f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$?
The question states that $|f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$ pointwisely a.e.

Comment: It is given that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n =f $ pointwisely a.e., so it follow that $|f_n|\rightarrow |f|$ a.e. and $|f_n-f|\rightarrow 0$ a.e. Now, it is easy to see that we also have $|f_n| -|f| -|f_n-f|\rightarrow 0$ a.e.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint to get you started: Apply Fatou's lemma to
$$
|f_n|+|f|-|f_n-f|\geq 0
$$
to find $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy application of a "generalized" dominated convergence theorem. You have $|f_n\chi_{A}| \leq |f_n|$, and $\int |f_n| \to \int |f|$. Since $f_n\chi_{A} \to f\chi_{A}$ almost everywhere, the generalized dominated convergence theorem gives $\int f_n\chi_{A} \to \int f\chi_{A}$